# How to do custom validation in my Django Modelform?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a ModelForm for this model, with this `unique_together`:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    selected_season = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    selected_subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_address = models.TextField()
    student_phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('student_name', 'selected_season', 'selected_subject'),)
```

The modelform is like this:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    student_address = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'materialize-textarea'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = '__all__'
```

How do I raise a validation error if the `unique_together` requirement is not met?

Comment: Django will internally do that, won't it?

Comment: Yes it did. It showed an integrity error. A regular user will not understand that